# How to retrieve a dynamic webpage (content was changed using DOM manipulation) using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a page which can accept several parameters. If parameters are supplied, it automatically perform a search. Otherwise, it just displays the search form.

Anyway, I', trying to load this dynamic page (just the search results) using using .get and .load functions. I am passing the required parameter and values so an automatic search can happen.

But the response I get from the HTTP request is the page without any search results. The target page uses ajax to retrieve the data from a MySQL DB and a combination of jquery/javascript to construct the search results section of the page.

This is the URL used: http://myhost.com/timetable/main?key=2452982&timetableonly=Y

If I copy/paste that URL into a new browser tab and hit enter, it will load the page and will display the search results.

These are jQuery codes I'm using.

**my code use to retrieve the page:**

```
function getTimetable(keynumber) {
    $("#target").load(baseurl + "/timetable/main?key=" + keynumber + "&timetableonly=Y", function() {
        console.log($("#target").html());
    });
    /*$.ajax({
        url: baseurl + "/timetable/main"
        , dataType: "html"
        , data: { key:keynumber, timetableonly:"Y" }
        , success: function(data, status) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });*/
}
```

I also tried something very simple on my target page (I removed the rest of my javascript code) and the updated page title was not showing in the response.

**updated javascript in target page**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    onLoad();

    function onLoad() {
        $(document).prop("title", "test page");
    }
});
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: CasperJS / PhantomJS might help

Comment: I've looked at PhantomJS and it's not possible to use in our corporate setup. :(